# How to segment whiteboard region?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

This is a case of whiteboard e-learning. The video shows the instructor teaching using the whiteboard. 
The student is asked to select four corners of the whiteboard. two of the corners may not be in the visible region. Can anyone suggest an algorithm which finds out the whiteboard area based of the four corner points selected?
I want to do something like what we see in camscanner app.

Answer (score 0):

If you can mark 4 points in image coordinates, then you can map these points to another quadrangle, or more specifically, rectangle using a homography. You will also need the whiteboard aspect ratio so that your result will have the correct X and Y equal scales. With this homography you can warp the video to straighten the board.

Note that the warping will cause some blurring of more distant areas and anything outside the whiteboard plane, e.g. the instructor, will be unrealistically warped.

If some of these points are outside the image, you will have to approximate their position for a proper view.